Plotting with Multiple axes in 3d
I have a specific visualisation in mind and I would to know if there exist any preexisting (preferable Python or with a Python wrapper) libraries that allow for this:

There are 5 positive axes glued together at 0, oriented in space in a particular way (think one axis pointing upwards, one downward, and three along a plane; the orientation may also be arbitrary).
Each pair of adjacent axes (quadrants) are at right angles, but, of course, not visualised that way.
Each data point is contained within two of these adjacent axes (quadrants).
The length of these axes is limited at 1, making the whole structure a cubical complex of 5 squares glued at 0 and along certain edges.

Here is a rough drawing:

Axes c, d and e are in the plane and the quadrants are ac, ad, ae, bc, bd, be, cd, ce, and de.
I want to make it interactive so the user can rotate the axes and view the distribution of the points. I do not want to turn this into 2d subplots since there will be 9 of them and I would like to plot a simple random walk on this cubical complex.

You can use any 3D visualization library like PyOpenGL since your axes are all positive you shouldn't have any problems with overlaps.
